# Why does the web browser size grow when i tilt it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, tilt

I am working with a windows phone app in visual studio that only have a web browser in it. I have problem with the layout. The app starts in portrait and it looks good. The web browser fills the whole screen. But when I tilt the phone to landscape-mode the web-browser get much bigger and you have to scroll a lot to get to the bottom of the page. I don't want it to be that big, i only want it to fill the screen.

Here is my code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage

x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
        To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
        keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
        replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
        with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

        For example:

            Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

        This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

        Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
        new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
        UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
        attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
        CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
     -->

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="http://www.google.se" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>

    </Grid>

    <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
        aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
        account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
        if the System Tray is hidden.

        Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
    <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is the browser itself bigger than the screen, or is it displaying scrollable content that's bigger than the screen?

Comment: It displays scrollable contents that is bigger than the screen.